# Increment Multiple Struct Variables using ForEach + Stepper SwiftUI

Tags: swift, struct, foreach, swiftui, uistepper

I have a list of toppings to include on a pizza. Each item in the list is a struct:

```
struct Topping: Identifiable {
    let name: String
    let price: Double
    @State var amount: Int
    let id = UUID()
}
```

The list is created in a Class in file MenuDataService.swift, is defined using static let, then initialized in a ViewModel file:

```
//FILE MenuDataService.swift
Class MenuDataService {
    static let toppingsList: [Topping] = [Topping(name: "Cheese", price: 3.00, amount: 0), Topping(name: "Sauce", price: 3.00, amount: 0)]
}

//FILE MenuViewModel.swift
Class MenuViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var toppingsList: [Topping]
    init() {
        toppingsList = MenuDataService.toppingsList
        self.toppingsList = toppingsList
    }
}
```

Inside the view im accessing the object using .environmentobject in the view. I'm iterating over the list of toppings using a ForEach loop, displaying the name and amount of toppings, followed by a stepper which should increment or decrement the 'amount' variable.

```
@EnvironmentObject private var vm = MenuViewModel
let toppingsList: [Topping]
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(toppingsList, id: \.id) { topping in
            Stepper("\(topping.name): \(topping.amount)", value: topping.$amount)
        }
    }
}

struct ExtraToppingsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ExtraToppingsView(toppingsList: MenuViewModel.init().toppingsList)
        .environmentObject(MenuViewModel())
    }
}
```

I get this error in the Stepper() Line of code: Accessing State's value outside of being installed on a View. This will result in a constant Binding of the initial value and will not update.

When clicking the '+' in the 'Cheese' stepper, it should increment the variable, and change the title to 'Cheese: 1', but the title stays the same. I'm assuming this has something to do with '@State var amount' variable, or some binding to the '$amount' variable in the stepper. If someone can point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Update: I was given this error - Accessing State's value outside of being installed on a View. This will result in a constant Binding of the initial value and will not update.

Comment: There are a few things going on here. `@State` can't be used outside of a view, so your model struct should *not* have any `@State` properties. Conversely, your `let toppingsList` will not be mutable -- it *should* be annotated with `@State`. Then, in your for each, you'll need [binding](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/bindable-swiftui-list-elements/). Probably a good opportunity to go through the Apple or Hacking With Swift SwiftUI tutorials and get familiar with some of the SwiftUI basics.

Comment: Watch [this](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10192) at about minute 20

Comment: Also, it is minor, but since `struct Topping` is `Identifiable`, you do not have to specifically use `.id`. Just iterate it like: `ForEach(toppingsList) { topping in`.

Comment: @jnpdx I might be formatting my code incorrectly, but I have the toppingsList declared inside a ViewModel, which will not let me use State. The static let toppingsList is then passed to a ViewModel where Published newVar is initialized to be equal to the list.

Comment: @jniuk Please include the relevant code in the form of a [mre]

Comment: In file MenuDataService: Class MenuDataService { static let toppingsList=...}; In file MenuViewModel: Class MenuViewModel: ObservableObject {@Published var toppingsList: [Topping]; init() {toppingsList = MenuDataService.toppingsList; self.toppingsList = toppingsList}}; I then access the ViewModel by using .environmentobject on the view I want to access, and initialize an environment object in the view. From here, I get the error mentioned above. @jnpdx

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a [mre]?

Comment: @jnpdx is this better? I added all the lines of code from the 3 files I was using, and added the error.

Comment: Yes, that’s better, although what you have isn’t valid Swift, so there are definitely some small differences between this Anna your real code. But, it’s probably enough for me to provide an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of your code is close -- there are just subtle differences required to make it work. See inline comments for my changes:

```
struct Topping: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let price: Double
    var amount: Int //don't include `@State` in non-Views
}

//no changes
class MenuDataService {
    static let toppingsList: [Topping] = [Topping(name: "Cheese", price: 3.00, amount: 0), Topping(name: "Sauce", price: 3.00, amount: 0)]
}

class MenuViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var toppingsList: [Topping]
    init() {
        toppingsList = MenuDataService.toppingsList
        //remove unnecessary duplicate assignment
    }
}

//This is the parent view -- may be called something different in your code
struct ContentView : View {
    @StateObject private var vm = MenuViewModel() //declare as @StateObject
    
    var body: some View {
        ExtraToppingsView()
            .environmentObject(vm) //pass the environment object
    }
}

struct ExtraToppingsView : View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var vm : MenuViewModel //no need to take the toppingsList parameter separately -- just use the environment object 

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach($vm.toppingsList) { $topping in //use element binding to get a mutable binding to each item
                Stepper("\(topping.name): \(topping.amount)", value: $topping.amount) //see change of the position of the $ character
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ExtraToppingsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ExtraToppingsView()
            .environmentObject(MenuViewModel())
    }
}
```

For more info on element binding: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/bindable-swiftui-list-elements/

Comment: Wow. You got it to work? Would you be able to explain it to me? The difference between my code and yours? (Except the @State in the struct definition, I understand that)

Comment: @jNiuk Did you read the inline comments -- I tried to explain all of the changes, and then I provided a link at the end that describes the element binding in more detail. Is there a part specifically that needs more explanation? Happy to provide it if I can.

Comment: This does work, one more question. What if I wanted to pass in a toppingsList for that view? In my program there are different lists for toppings (cheese, meats, veggies) and I want to reuse that view. That's why early I included the parameter in my old code. Thanks for all your help @jnpdx

Comment: Currently I have a really hacky solution of iterating through the entire state object list, and comparing string titles, and displaying based on that. It works, but if there is a better solution, im willing to learn :)

Comment: If you wanted a specific list for that single view, I'd think you'd want to use `@StateObject private var vm = MenuViewModel()` on the `View` itself. EnvironmentObject (which you used in your original code) implies that it's going to be used in more of a global state (or at least across multiple views).

Comment: I read the article you gave me. I ended up passing the struct using @ Binding on the child views. There is a new problem though, when doing this, after incrementing or decrementing the stepper, the view dismisses itself to the previous view. When reloading the stepper view, the variable has been correctly changed, but will still crash/dismiss to the previous when changing it. Any idea why this happens? If you need my code let me know.

Comment: @jNiuk sounds like a good candidate for a new question, since that's navigation is beyond the scope of this one. I'd be happy to take a look if you make one.

Comment: I just did! I posted it on my profile, its generally the same format, but if its missing anything let me know. I can screen record or post photos if needed